# Functional characterization of zeroth law of thermodynamics [Sepration of Variables]

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Zeroth law of thermodynamics is [stated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics#cite_ref-L.26Y_56_4-0) also as:

> If A is in thermal equilibrium with B and if B is in thermal equilibrium with C, then A is in thermal equilibrium with C.

This can be formulated as, let system `A` and `B` be in equilibrium iff $f(A, B) = 0$ ( i have identified the system with its properties). Then according to zeroth law, for another system `C`, $f(A,C) = 0 , \, f(B,C) \implies F(A,B) = 0$.

Under these constraints of $f$, we have: if $f(A,B) = 0$ then it should be expressible in the form $g(A) = h(B)$, $g$, and $h$ being arbitrary functions. How do we prove this statements?

Vaguely, this feels like same arguments as we use in separation of variables but I am not able to rigorously prove it.

I am not sure, if the title of the question appropriately reflects what I am asking. Please modify if necessary.